# Loggin a spring boot application

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

Is there a efficient way of creating an activity log for a user. When the user changes the data log it, when admin changes there data log it and so on. Only way Im thing of doing this is posting at every api request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to log every single method that you want to be logged.

If you want to save time you can look at Spring AOP which allows you to extract a cross cutting concern, such as logging, into a seperate configuration file and then you can target a whole set of methods based on whatever criteria you choose (pointcut).

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-aop